# Why we get "input stream can not be null" error while implementing Bulk API

Tags: bulk-api, error-messages

i tried implementing an example of bulk api provided at link : http://code.google.com/p/sfdc-bulkapi-demo/source/browse/trunk/demo/src/com/jeffdouglas/BulkLoader.java

At run time, i am getting following error :

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input stream can not be null

How can i solve it, Please help.

Comment: Which line in the sample is throwing that exception?
As a wild guess I'd say it can't find the CSV file defined in `csvFileName`.

Comment: Code is properly executed upto line:  System.out.println("Awaiting results..." + incomplete.size());     AFter this it throws error, so i feel error is in line: BatchInfo[] statusList = connection.getBatchInfoList(job.getId())
          .getBatchInfo();
 Also, csvFileName variable is pointing to a Valid CSV file on my system

Comment: The stack trace should point to the exact line of code throwing the exception. Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @Peace, can you add the resulting stacktrace to the question? Being line 222 it would appear the exception is occurring in the RestConnection.

Comment: input stream can not be null
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input stream can not be null
 at com.sforce.ws.parser.MXParser.setInput(MXParser.java:522)
 at com.sforce.ws.parser.XmlInputStream.setInput(XmlInputStream.java:64)
 at com.sforce.async.RestConnection.parseAndThrowException(RestConnection.java:112)
 at com.sforce.async.RestConnection.doHttpGet(RestConnection.java:283)
 at com.sforce.async.RestConnection.getBatchInfoList(RestConnection.java:190)
 at com.jeffdouglas.BulkLoader.awaitCompletion(BulkLoader.java:222)
 at com.jeffdouglas.BulkLoader.runJob(BulkLoader.java:159)

Comment: at com.jeffdouglas.BulkLoader.run(BulkLoader.java:52)
 at com.jeffdouglas.BulkLoader.main(BulkLoader.java:37)

Comment: (BulkLoader.java:222)-> BatchInfo[] statusList = connection.getBatchInfoList(job.getId())  
(BulkLoader.java:159) ->  awaitCompletion(connection, job, batchInfoList);    
(BulkLoader.java:52) ->  runJob(sObject, userName, password, csvFileName);  
(BulkLoader.java:37) ->  example.run();

Comment: Same exception here. Seems to be occuring at `for (String resultId : queryResults)
        inputStream = bulkConnection.getQueryResultStream(jobDetail.getJobid(), batchId,
resultId);`

And the issue seems to be sporadic.